# sendmail localhost host name lookup failure

Tags: sendmail, localhost, host, failed

I am starting to see a certain type of email that is causing problems for our users.  I am running sendmail on Fedora with mimedefang-filter.  When this certain type of spam comes in with random characters in the subject and body, it eventually (after several failed attempts) gets put into the INBOX instead of JUNK folder even though it is properly flagged as spam.  Dovecot sieve gets confused somehow.  Here are the errors in maillog:

```
Mar  8 03:47:51 afomail sendmail[22473]: v23Hplpr011711: SYSERR(root): timeout writing message to localhost
Mar  8 03:47:51 afomail sendmail[22473]: v23Hplpr011711: to=<username@domain.tld>, delay=4+15:56:03, xdelay=00:00:05, mailer=local, pri=10129675, relay=localhost, dsn=4.4.2, stat=Deferred: Name server: localhost: host name lookup failure
```

The proper entries are in resolv.conf and this only happens with a tiny fraction of email volume.  But something about these emails prevents sendmail from being able to find itself (localhost).  How can I fix this?

Contents of nssswitch.conf

```
passwd:     files sss
shadow:     files sss
group:      files sss

hosts:      files dns myhostname mymachines

bootparams: nisplus [NOTFOUND=return] files

ethers:     files
netmasks:   files
networks:   files
protocols:  files
rpc:        files
services:   files sss

netgroup:   files sss

publickey:  nisplus

automount:  files sss
aliases:    files nisplus
```

hosts:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4 mydomain.com
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
```

resolv.conf

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

results of grep 'D{MTAHost' /etc/mail/submit.cf

```
D{MTAHost}[127.0.0.1]
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you include also results produced by `grep 'D{MTAHost' /etc/mail/submit.cf`?

Comment: done ... added it to original question above